# Finding the probability of a random integer between random integers

Tags: probability, random-variables

My calculator allows you to generate pseudo-random integers in between 2 values, even if the values specified are randomly generated themselves. On a calculator it looks like:

```
RanInt#(0,RanInt#(1,RanInt#(2,RanInt#(3,RanInt#(4,5)))))
```

As in "a random number between 0 and a random number between 1 and a random number between 2 and a random number between 3 and a random number between 4 and 5"

This cycle could potentially go on forever.

I'm finding it extremely difficult to figure out a way to calculate the odds of a certain number being generated, any ideas?

I put the thing in python just to find how many of one number is generated in a sample, only I still don't know how you could calculate the real probability. I feel like it might be something extremely easy that I overlooked, the more I think about this the less it makes sense.

```
import random
a=0
g=0
for i in range(100000000):
    e=random.randint(4,5)
    d=random.randint(3,e)
    c=random.randint(2,d)
    b=random.randint(1,c)
    a=random.randint(0,b)
    if a==5:
        g=g+1
print(g)
```

A sample of 100 million gave 137988 5s generated.

Comment: $\dfrac{10^8}{6!} \approx 138889$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trace the probabilities through the process:

\begin{array}{c|cc}
&5&4&3&2&1&0\\\hline
e&\frac12&\frac12\\
d&\frac16&\frac5{12}&\frac5{12}\\
c&\frac1{24}&\frac{13}{72}&\frac7{18}&\frac7{18}\\
b&\frac1{120}&\frac{77}{1440}&\frac{791}{4320}&\frac{1631}{4320}&\frac{1631}{4320}\\
a&\frac1{720}&\frac{29}{2400}&\frac{4999}{86400}&\frac{47617}{259200}&\frac{96547}{259200}&\frac{96547}{259200}
\end{array}

For instance, $P(c=4)=\frac14P(d=5)+\frac13P(d=4)$. Note that the denominators in the $5$ column are the factorials, since they get multiplied by a factor $\frac1n$ in each step.